# Update HTML to have closing tags with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, gulp, cheerio

> ***Note:** See the solution below!*

## The Problem

By default both JS and jQuery will remove closing tags for empty `<foreignObject>`'s. Normally this wouldn't be a problem. However, in IE11 the following warning will be thrown due to the self-closing elements.

```
HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.
```

## Case Study

I'm attempting to utilize Gulp to add closing tags to a series of SVG files. SVG files are formatted as such initially:

*Email.svg*,

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="#AFAFB0" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1,5 L23,5 C23.5522847,5 24,5.44771525 24,6 L24,18 C24,18.5522847 23.5522847,19 23,19 L1,19 C0.44771525,19 6.76353751e-17,18.5522847 0,18 L0,6 C-6.76353751e-17,5.44771525 0.44771525,5 1,5 Z M21.2034005,7.09747208 L12,13.8789251 L2.79659952,7.09747208 C2.57428949,6.93366469 2.26127947,6.98109045 2.09747208,7.20340048 C1.93366469,7.42571051 1.98109045,7.73872053 2.20340048,7.90252792 L11.7034005,14.9025279 C11.8797785,15.0324907 12.1202215,15.0324907 12.2965995,14.9025279 L21.7965995,7.90252792 C22.0189095,7.73872053 22.0663353,7.42571051 21.9025279,7.20340048 C21.7387205,6.98109045 21.4257105,6.93366469 21.2034005,7.09747208 Z"/>
</svg>
```

In my gulpfile I'm utilizing [gulp-cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cheerio) to attempt to manipulate the HTML by adding the closing tag to any self-closing elements.

*gulpfile.js*

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const cheerio = require('gulp-cheerio');

const rootPath = './src/assets';
const paths = {
  svg: {
    in: `${rootPath}/icons/raw/**/*.svg`,
    out: `${rootPath}/icons/svg`,
  }
};

const svg = () => {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.svg.in)
    .pipe(cheerio({
      run: ($, file) => {
        const updatedHtml = $.html().replace(/<\s*([^\s>]+)([^>]*)\/\s*>/g, '<$1$2></$1>');
        // Update self-closing elements to have a closing tag
        $('svg').replaceWith(updatedHtml);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.svg.out));
};
```

If I `console.log` the `updatedHtml` it will have the closing tag. However, when I utilize `.html()` or `.replaceWith()` the output has a self-closing tag.

I have also tried the `gulp-replace` package. The below producse the same result as the above.

```js
const svg = () => {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.svg.in)
    .pipe(replace(/<\s*([^\s>]+)([^>]*)\/\s*>/g, '<$1$2></$1>'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.svg.out));
};
```

## Question

How do I get the output to include the closing tag? Is there a better package for this or is this not really possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply write the `updatedHtml` string to a file?

Comment: This is just a bug in IE. It's harmless but as far as I'm aware impossible to suppress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels like a work-around but got the SVG saving by removing `.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.svg.out));` and instead making use of `fs`.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const cheerio = require('gulp-cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

const rootPath = './src/assets';
const paths = {
  svg: {
    in: `${rootPath}/icons/raw/**/*.svg`,
    out: `${rootPath}/icons/svg`,
  }
};

const svg = () => {
  let dirName;
  let fileName;

  return gulp
    .src(paths.svg.in)
    .pipe(rename((path) => {
      // Ensure the file name is kebob-case
      path.basename = path.basename
        .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\ ]/g, '')
        .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2')
        .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
        .toLowerCase();

      dirName = path.dirname;
      fileName = path.basename;
    }))
    .pipe(cheerio({
      run: ($, file) => {
        $('svg').attr('class', `svg-${fileName}`);

        const path = `${paths.svg.out.svg}/${dirName}/${fileName}.svg`;
        const updatedHtml = $.html().replace(/<\s*([^\s>]+)([^>]*)\/\s*>/g, '<$1$2></$1>');

        fs.writeFile(path, updatedHtml);
      }
    }))
};
```

which, based on the above SVG, returns

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewbox="0 0 24 24" class="svg-email">
  <path fill="#AFAFB0" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1,5 L23,5 C23.5522847,5 24,5.44771525 24,6 L24,18 C24,18.5522847 23.5522847,19 23,19 L1,19 C0.44771525,19 6.76353751e-17,18.5522847 0,18 L0,6 C-6.76353751e-17,5.44771525 0.44771525,5 1,5 Z M21.2034005,7.09747208 L12,13.8789251 L2.79659952,7.09747208 C2.57428949,6.93366469 2.26127947,6.98109045 2.09747208,7.20340048 C1.93366469,7.42571051 1.98109045,7.73872053 2.20340048,7.90252792 L11.7034005,14.9025279 C11.8797785,15.0324907 12.1202215,15.0324907 12.2965995,14.9025279 L21.7965995,7.90252792 C22.0189095,7.73872053 22.0663353,7.42571051 21.9025279,7.20340048 C21.7387205,6.98109045 21.4257105,6.93366469 21.2034005,7.09747208 Z"></path>
</svg>
```